# How to load calculation input from text file with Python?

Tags: python, text, numbers, line, calculation

I have a text file containing:

```
Number Name subject1 subject2 subject3 subject4 subject5
1234567 Jan 5 7 0 6 4
3526435 Marie 5 5 7 0 0
2230431 Kees 6 10 0 8 6
7685433 André 4 7 8 7 5
0364678 Antoinette 0 2 8 8 8
1424354 Jerôme 7 9 0 5 0
4536576 Kamal 8 0 8 7 8
1256033 Diana 0 0 0 0 0
5504657 Petra 6 6 7 0 6
9676575 Malika 0 6 0 0 8
0253756 Samira 3 8 6 7 10
```

I want to calculate the average grades for each student (if grade = 0 then it is not included), and I want to calculate the average grades for each subject (again, without calculating 0).

In my own code I copied all of the information and put it into lists.

The problem I am facing, is that I need my Python program to read the text file and calculate with the given numbers.

So far, this is all I have:

```
i = 0
file = open("resultaten.txt", "r")

for x in file:
    if i == 0:
        print("Lines: ")

    else:
        x = x.split()
        print(i, x)
    i +=1
```

How would one use a text file to calculate specific characters in a line?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we convert this to a dictionary we will have a lot of flexibility with what we want to do with the information. This can be done with a little effort.  We can use the first line to create our `keys` then we can zip those keys with each other line, then create a list of tuples by zipping those lists. From there we can use a dictionary constructor to create our list of dictionaries.  Now we just have to gather all `keys` from this list of dictionaries that are `subjects` for each item in the list, map those to ints and create an exception for when the student has scored all `0`s. If not we filter out the `0`'s from a complete list and then calculate average. Next to get averages for each `subject` we can extract all the values that are connected to that subject, not taking values that are `0`, same we map `ints` and then calculate average. I threw in some text justification for appearances, not neccessary. The process for the remaining subjects would be the same just swap out the subject.

```
with open('text.txt') as f:
    content = [line.split() for line in f]

keys = content[0]

lst = list(zip([keys]*(len(content)-1), content[1:]))
x = [zip(i[0], i[1]) for i in lst]
z = [dict(i) for i in x]

print('Average Grades'.center(30))
for i in z:
    subs =[i['subject1'], i['subject2'], i['subject3'], i['subject4'], i['subject5']]
    subs = list(map(int, subs))
    if sum(subs) == 0:
        print('{:<10} average grade: {:>4}'.format(i['Name'], 0))
    else:
        subs = list(filter(lambda x: x >0, subs))
        avg = round(sum(subs)/len(subs), 2)
        print('{:<10} average grade: {:>4}'.format(i['Name'], avg))

sub1 = [i['subject1'] for i in z if i['subject1'] != '0']
sub1 = list(map(int, sub1))
sub1_avg = sum(sub1)/len(sub1)
print('\nAverage Grade for Subject 1: {}'.format(sub1_avg))
```

> ```
>         Average Grades        
> Jan        average grade:  5.5
> Marie      average grade: 5.67
> Kees       average grade:  7.5
> André      average grade:  6.2
> Antoinette average grade:  6.5
> Jerôme     average grade:  7.0
> Kamal      average grade: 7.75
> Diana      average grade:    0
> Petra      average grade: 6.25
> Malika     average grade:  7.0
> Samira     average grade:  6.8
>
> Average Grade for Subject 1: 5.5
> ```

Answer (score 1):

These kinds of operations are easier to do with a library designed for working with tabular data such as yours. [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) is a great example, albeit it can be a bit daunting to get into, especially for someone who doesn't have a lot of experience with python. Anyway, here's one way to achieve what (I think) you want, using pandas. Your exclusion of zero values makes it a bit more complicated, hence the cryptic code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# ^This line makes sure python is able to read some weird
# accented characters.

# Importing variaous libraries
import sys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Depending on your version of python, we need to import
# a different library for reading your input data as a
# string. This step is not required, you should probably
# use the pandas function called read_csv(), if you have
# your file stored locally.
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO

input_data = StringIO("""Number Name subject1 subject2 subject3 subject4 subject5
1234567 Jan 5 7 0 6 4
3526435 Marie 5 5 7 0 0
2230431 Kees 6 10 0 8 6
7685433 André 4 7 8 7 5
0364678 Antoinette 0 2 8 8 8
1424354 Jerôme 7 9 0 5 0
4536576 Kamal 8 0 8 7 8
1256033 Diana 0 0 0 0 0
5504657 Petra 6 6 7 0 6
9676575 Malika 0 6 0 0 8
0253756 Samira 3 8 6 7 10
""")

# Read data, specify that columns are delimited by space,
# using the sep= argument.
df = pd.read_csv(input_data, sep=" ")

# Find all column names contain subject scores, based on their name
# We just pick all columns that starts with the string "subject".
subject_columns = [c for c in df.columns if c.startswith("subject")]
print subject_columns

# Calculate mean score for each subject by finding the sum of all scores
# for each subject, then divide it by the number of data points for each
# subject that does not equal (or is greater than) 0.
for subject in subject_columns:
    df["%s_mean" % subject] = float(df[subject].sum()) / float(len(df[subject].loc[df[subject] > 0]))

# Calculate mean for each student, without 0s
# The .replace(0, np.NaN).count(axis=1) is just a trick to find the
# number of non-zero values in each row. In short, it replaces all
# values that are 0 with NaN, so that the count() function ignores
# those values when calculating the number of data points that are
# present in the dataset. I.e. it disregards values that are 0,
# so that they're excluded from the mean calculation.
df["student_mean"] = df[subject_columns].sum(axis=1) / df[subject_columns].replace(0, np.NaN).count(axis=1)

# This just configures pandas to print all columns in our dataset,
# and not truncate the print-out to fit to the screen.
pd.set_option("display.max_columns", 1000)

# Print out our final dataframe.
print df
```

The final dataset looks like this:

```
     Number        Name  subject1  subject2  subject3  subject4  subject5  subject1_mean  subject2_mean  subject3_mean  subject4_mean  subject5_mean  student_mean
0   1234567         Jan         5         7         0         6         4            5.5       6.666667       7.333333       6.857143          6.875      5.500000
1   3526435       Marie         5         5         7         0         0            5.5       6.666667       7.333333       6.857143          6.875      5.666667
2   2230431        Kees         6        10         0         8         6            5.5       6.666667       7.333333       6.857143          6.875      7.500000
3   7685433       André         4         7         8         7         5            5.5       6.666667       7.333333       6.857143          6.875      6.200000
4    364678  Antoinette         0         2         8         8         8            5.5       6.666667       7.333333       6.857143          6.875      6.500000
5   1424354      Jerôme         7         9         0         5         0            5.5       6.666667       7.333333       6.857143          6.875      7.000000
6   4536576       Kamal         8         0         8         7         8            5.5       6.666667       7.333333       6.857143          6.875      7.750000
7   1256033       Diana         0         0         0         0         0            5.5       6.666667       7.333333       6.857143          6.875           NaN
8   5504657       Petra         6         6         7         0         6            5.5       6.666667       7.333333       6.857143          6.875      6.250000
9   9676575      Malika         0         6         0         0         8            5.5       6.666667       7.333333       6.857143          6.875      7.000000
10   253756      Samira         3         8         6         7        10            5.5       6.666667       7.333333       6.857143          6.875      6.800000
```

Note that you need to install the pandas module for this to work. You also need the [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) module.

Answer (score 0):

You can index your `x.split()` function, I would avoid rewriting `x`.

`y = x.split()
Number = y[0]
Name   = y[1]
...`

Or

`Number, Name, subject1, subject2, subject3, subject4, subject5 = x.split()`

Then, you can compute the mean.
You can try something like...

```
    Number, Name, subject1, subject2, subject3, subject4, subject5 = x.split()
    subjects = [float(subject1), float(subject2), float(subject3), float(subject4), float(subject5)]
    sum = 0
    zero_count = 0
    for subject in subjects:
       sum += subject
       if subject is 0:
          zero_count += 1
    # this will print the mean
    print(i,  sum/(len(subjects)-zero_count)
```

This code block can replace what is in your `else` statement and it will print index and the mean with excluded '0' grades.